# How to check if I'm currently the database owner for SQL 2000/2005/2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dbo

I can't remember how to do this in a TSQL query.  It was a one-liner, good for testing before running DML.  The query was something similar to SELECT IS_DBO() or SELECT IS(DBO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`IS_MEMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186271.aspx) function:

```
SELECT IS_MEMBER('db_owner')
```